# file not found exception for reading contents of file

Tags: java

I am trying to read contents from file, but I am getting file not found exception.

Please help me out. I am using below code.

```
 File f = new File("C:/sample/welcome.txt"); //working
 System.out.println("File path  ="+f.getPath());                              
 System.out.println("File name  = "+f.getName());
 System.out.println("File size = "+f.length());
 String ret = "";

 HttpURLConnection connection = null;

 try {

      int size = (int) f.getName().length();
      byte[] data = new byte[size];
      String _contrainerName1 ="/development";
      // String content = new String("This is my first upload to dropbox");
      //String fileName ="test17.txt";

      try {
          InputStream inputStream =  new FileInputStream(f.getName());

          if ( inputStream != null ) {
             DataInputStream in1 = new DataInputStream(inputStream);
             // InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
             BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in1));

             String receiveString = "";
             StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

             while ( (receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
                  stringBuilder.append(receiveString);
             }

             inputStream.close();
             ret = stringBuilder.toString();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.out.println("login activity");

    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.out.println("login activity");
    }
```

Comment: I believe your code formatting is broken and split into two parts. Please double check it.

Comment: You have this tagged as Android. Android does not have a `C:` drive.

Comment: I am running as simple java application using eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to read a file in a Windows file system, you should use double backlash:

```
  File f = new File("C:\\sample\\welcome.txt");
```

Also, you can instantiate the FileInputStream passing directly the File object

```
  InputStream inputStream =  new FileInputStream(f);
```

Comment: @superfine123 Glad to help. Mark the answer as accepted, if you please.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do is check whether that file actually exists in your C:\ drive.

**C:\ drive**

C:/sample/welcome.txt

The backslash being the first hint:)

Comment: the file is present in c drive and I have already tried with backslash, but still facing same exception

Comment: Are you in Android? Or in windows?

Answer (score 0):

```
     try {

        File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File file = new File(sdcard, "location/of/filename.txt");
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
            total.append(line);
            total.append('\n');
        }
        String ttt = total.toString();
        TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
        txt.setText(ttt);



        r.close();
        Log.d("File", "File contents: " + total);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Exact code to read file in android

Answer (score 0):

How CommonsWire said, in Android `C:` doesn't exist.
You have *`getExternalStorageDirectory`*.
Try with this:

```
File myfile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "myFile.txt");
```

Comment: on above usage,I am getting as "The method getExternalStorageDirectory() is undefined for the type Environment".

Comment: @superfine123 are in using Android? Have you imported this Environment class? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html

Comment: I am trying to do currently on windows

Comment: @superfine123 but you tagged Android... no sense